# Java: I have joda Start and End DateTime, how would I slice it into N pieces?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a start Date and end Date and hence I have a duration it could be a small duration in hours or it could be a long duration in years, how can I slice it up in number of equal pieces of duration, for example :

below duration is of approx. 1 month

```
startDate = 2017-03-01 00:00:00.000Z
endDate = 2017-04-01 00:00:00.000Z
```

How would I slice it up in 2 equal pieces ?
something like below :

```
startDate1 =  2017-03-01 00:00:00.000Z
endDate1 = 2017-03-15 00:00:00.000Z

startDate2 = 2017-03-15 00:00:00.000Z
endDate2 = 2017-04-01 00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Please downvote with a reason, if you simply down vote a question without any reason then how could someone know what he/she has done wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `LocalData`, use the function 'getLocalMillis' for both dates, then loop from start to end with an interval of your choosing.

Pseudocode:

```
long start = startDate.getLocalMillis();
long end = endDate.getLocalMillis();
long interval = (end-start)/numberOfIntervals;
for(long i = start+interval; i < end; i+=interval){
  LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(i);
  //do something with ld
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Case some is looking equal denominator between given time here is code.

```
private List<Interval> splitDateTime(long start, long end, int intervalNo) {
        long interval = (end - start) / intervalNo;
        List<Interval> list = new ArrayList<Interval>();
        for (long i = start + interval; i < end; i += interval) {
            list.add(new Interval(start, i));
            start=start + interval;
        }
        list.add(new Interval(start, end));
        return list;
    }
```